# Preencher classe agregada a partir de dataTable utilizando um Dataset com LINQ C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, linq, ado.net

Estou com dificuldades em preencher uma classe agregada em C#. É possível usando LINQ? Alguém tem algum exemplo de como solucionar este problema usando o retorno de um `DataTable` ou `DataSet`?

[image: Diagrama]

```
public class OrderDetails
{
 . . .
}

public class Order
{
     private List<OrderDetails> details;
     public Person(OrderDetails pdetails)
     {
         this.details.Add(pdetails);
     }
     . . .
}
```

Comment: Sua intenção também não está clara. Você possui uma classe Order e deseja adicionar OrderDetails à ela? De que forma você deseja que a adição seja feita? Via UI? Ou esta é uma classe que será preenchida num modelo de dados e retornada para o cliente?

Comment: Então, tenho um método que retorna um DataTable, gostaria de preencher esta List<OderDetails> da Classe Order, ou seja, trazendo uma coleção de OrderDetails. Por exemplo no meu SQL estou usando "SELECT O.Id, O.date, O.person, O.value, D.* FROM Order INNER JOIN OrderDetails ON O.id = D.fk_Order", como faço para passar os dados para a coleção OrderDetails da Classe Order?

Comment: Certo, agora compreendi. Te aconselho a mudar sua pergunta para algo como "preencher classe agregada a partir de dataTable". Já já te darei uma resposta.

Comment: Pronto..mudei o título

Comment: Só mais uma dica: adicione a query utilizada no DataSet à pergunta. Futuras pessoas que tenham a mesma dúvida podem não entender direito minha implementação sem ver a fonte de dados, e um comentário não é o melhor lugar para um dado importante do problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você vai precisar iterar em cada resultado do DataTable e agrupar as informações de cada Order em um dicionário indexado pelo seu Id, para poder agregar nas mesmas instâncias de Order os OrderDetails.

O primeiro passo é tornar a lista de detalhes pública:

```
public class Order
{
     //Precisa ser público, já que a modelagem sugere que um Order 
     //pode ter mais de um OrderDetails. Precisaremos adicionar 
     //mais detalhes ao iterar nas linhas do DataSet.
     public List<OrderDetails> Details { get; set; } 

     //Mantive o OrderDetail sendo passado no construtor, já que o
     //modelo explicita que um Order deve possuir ao menos um OrderDetail
     public Order(OrderDetails detail) 
     {
         this.Details = new List<OrderDetails>();
         this.Details.Add(detail);
     }
}
```

Agora sim podemos iterar nos resultados do DataSet e preencher a classe. 
Vou assumir algumas premissas:

1) de que o Id de Order é uma String. Esta premissa baseia-se somente no fato de ser mais fácil lidar com String no exemplo. Faça as conversões necessárias para seu código.

2) de que seu Dataset já foi configurado e um DataTable já foi criado a partir dele. Caso esta premissa seja falsa, favor pesquisar antes sobre como acessar dados do DB via DataSet:

```
private IEnumerable<Order> GetOrdersFromDataTable(DataTable ordersTable)
{
    var orderDict = new Dictionary<string, Order>(); 
    foreach (DataRow dr in ordersTable.Rows)
    {
        var orderDetail = new OrderDetail();
        //Todo: Preencher as propriedades do OrderDetail.
        string id = dr["Id"].ToString());
        if (!orderDict.ContainsKey(id))
        {
             var order = new Order(orderDetail);
             //Todo: Preencher as propriedades do Order.
             orderDict.Add(id, order);
        }
        else
             orderDict[id].Details.Add(orderDetail);
    }
    return orderDict.Values;
}
```

**Edição:** Você perguntou se era possível preencher as classes com linq, mas acredito que você quis dizer Linq2Sql, que é uma ferramenta para abstrair o acesso à fonte de dados, mapeando tabelas em classes e permitindo consultas utilizando linq. Existe uma outra biblioteca, porém, chamada Entity Framework, mais robusta que a anterior, que veio para substituí-la. Se estiver interessado em saber mais, sugiro pesquisar sobre EF e tentar implementar um acesso ao seu banco utilizando-o. A documentação é extensa e há material inclusive em português. Caso tenha qualquer dúvida, faça outra pergunta no StackOverflow, para que esta não se torne ampla demais.

Comment: Tranquilo mas já é uma início obrigado...

Comment: Adequei a implementação das classes respeitando a modelagem e o código para preencher as classes teve de ser adaptado.

Comment: Ok, mais uma vez muito obrigado.